# Gcloud auth for all users on a server

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I am trying to setup a Gcloud Auth Login for an account on a server that will cover all users.

i.e.
I login using an administrator account and issue the command..
e.g.
gcloud auth login auser@anemail.com
go through the steps required and when I issue the issue the Gcloud Auth List command I get the right result.

But other users cannot see it.
i.e. we use sap data services that use a proxy account on the server when it is running
e.g.
proxyaccount@mail.com

but that user cannot see the the authorized user I authorized using the administrator account.

I get error "you do not currently have an active account selected"

The "other" accounts do not have administration access nor do we want them to, and besides I don't want to have to go through this process for each and every account that connects to the server.

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Each user gets its own gcloud configuration folder. You can see which configuration folder is used by gcloud by running `gcloud info`.

Note that if your server is a VM on GCP you do not need to configure credentials as they are obtained from metadata server for the VM.

Sharing user credentials is not a good practice. If you need to do this your users can set `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` environment variable to point to one shared configuration folder. Also you should at least use service account for this purpose and activate it via `gcloud auth activate-service-account` instead of using credentials obtained via `gcloud auth login`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've followed your advice but I can't make the other accounts recognize the credentials set up. I set the environment variable CLOUDSDK_CONFIG to the required folder but the other accounts don't recognize it ? If I do an echo %CLOUDSDK_CONFIG% it doesn't recognize the value set ?

Comment: You would have to set CLOUDSDK_CONFIG environment variable as admin for all users of the machine. On windows, for example on administrator command prompt you could run `SETX CLOUDSDK_CONFIG "C:\Path\To\CloudSDK\Shared\Config" /M` (use your path). Then any *newly open* command prompt will  have that setting.